# Modal popup extender its working fine but in my aspx page all button's postback event is not fired

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, ajax

linkbutton on which i want to show modal popup extender

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="Feedback" runat="server" CssClass="hyperlinkann" OnClientClick="return false;">Give your feedback</asp:LinkButton>

    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Feedback"
                                                PopupControlID="popuppanel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="Cancel">
                                                </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Here i don't use okcontrlID because i want to do some coding on submit

```
      <asp:Panel ID="popuppanel" runat="server" CssClass="confirm-dialog" DefaultButton="okbutton">

        <div class="divpopup">
            <h3 style="color:Black;font-weight:bold;">Feedback</h3>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_comments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="190" Height="50" placeholder="Give Feedback" required="require"
            BorderColor="Black"></asp:TextBox>

            <br /><br />
           <asp:Button ID="okbutton" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="popupbutton" 
                onclick="okbutton_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="popupbutton" /> 
        </div>

     </asp:Panel>
```